# Monitor changes in categories field using outlook vba

Tags: vba, events, outlook, categories

Is there a VBA command in outlook 2010 that fires an event upon detecting changes in the [categories] field of an item in a certain folder?

Please refer to the make up pseudo code below (does not work):

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set Items = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    If Item.Categories = "ABC" AND Item.PropertyChange = "Categories" Then
        ' do something when [categories] field is changed to ABC.
    End if
End Sub
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.propertychange

Not much to go on.

Answer (score 0):

`Items.ItemChange` on the folder items and `MailItem.Write` events are fired when any property changes. It is your responsibility to figure out which property was changed.

`MailItem.PropertyChange` will pass the name of the modified property, but it will only fire for a particular item (which means you must track open items and selection change to track the items that the user can modify).

Comment: Thank you for your hints. Not much to go on searching the MS DOCS and the internet regarding propertychange on mailitems. I modified the above code building from your hints, but I can not verify it's functionality as of now, since I will not be at the office for a while. Would the amended code work?

Comment: You can see live events in OutlookSpy - open the item, click CurrentItem button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the Events tab. Modify any property, look at the log at the bottom of that tab.